# ubuntu text-mode boot welcome  Banner

Tags: text-mode

im using ubuntu 14.04 and i edited grub so that it boots into text mode

i want to display a message in the login screen like this:

```
 _            _   
| |_ ___  ___| |_ 
| __/ _ \/ __| __|
| ||  __/\__ \ |_ 
 \__\___||___/\__|

login:
```

i also want to run this command so when user runs the os in VM it displays the ip address in the login screen :

```
ifconfig | perl -nle 's/dr:(\S+)/print $1/e'
```

is there a file should i edit ? i want to do it like ssh Banner and welcome message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For your ASCII art

Edit the file `/etc/issue`

```
sudo nano /etc/issue
```

and add your ASCII Art.

---

Add system information with:

- `b`   Insert the baudrate of the current line.
- `d`   Insert the current date.
- `s`   Insert the system name, the name of the operating system.
- `l`   Insert the name of the current tty line.
- `m`   Insert the architecture identifier of the machine, e.g., i686.
- `n`   Insert the nodename of the machine, also known as the hostname.
- `o`   Insert the domainname of the machine.
- `r`   Insert the release number of the kernel, e.g., 2.6.11.12.
- `t`   Insert the current time.
- `u`   Insert the number of current users logged in.
- `U`   Insert the string "1 user" or " users" where  is the number of current users logged in.
- `v`   Insert the version of the OS, e.g., the build-date etc.

eg:

```
Ubuntu 15.04 \n
```

for the hostname

---

### For the IP address

1. Create a file `/etc/issue-standard` and add your ASCII art.
2. Create a script `/etc/network/if-up.d/show-ip-address`

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/network/if-up.d/show-ip-address
   ```

   add the code below

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   if [ "$METHOD" = loopback ]; then
       exit 0
   fi

   # Only run from ifup.
   if [ "$MODE" != start ]; then
       exit 0
   fi

   cp /etc/issue-standard /etc/issue
   LANG=C sudo /sbin/ifconfig | grep "inet addr" | grep -v "127.0.0.1" | awk '{ print $2 }' | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' >> /etc/issue
   echo "" >> /etc/issue
   ```

   and make the script executable

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/show-ip-address
   ```

When the network interface is brought up, the file `/etc/issue` will be rewritten.

<sub>[Partial source](http://offbytwo.com/2008/05/09/show-ip-address-of-vm-as-console-pre-login-message.html)</sub>